# How can I access a List<object> properties?

Tags: c#

I have a List of objects and each object is a another List of objects, so for example, I am passing `List<object> cars` to one method and I want to get all the properties of one of the objects, but when I try to do:

```
var props = cars.First().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                         BindingFlags.Public |
                                                         BindingFlags.Instance);
```

It gives me the properties of System.Object (Count, Capacity, and my list of objects)

When I look at cars which in this case is called list, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Marc, I am updating my post with a screen shot.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I am reflecting through the each objects properties and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have said: each object is another list of objects. The things you report (Count, Capacity etc) *are* the properties of that inner list. If you want to go deeper, cast it as `IList` and take a look inside the inner list.

Comment: Does the screen shot help?  As you can see `list` has one object and this object contains 7 more objects.

Comment: @Xaisoft indeed, but your code currently is looking only at the inner list, not the sub-items. Hence what I said in my answer.

Comment: Marc, I did the following, but not sure if it could be more concise?  `var list2 = (IList) list[0];` which gives me 7 objects and then `var list3 = list2[0].GetType().GetProperties();` which gives me a list of properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<object>> listOfCarObjects = new List<object>();

listOfCarObjects.Add(new List<object>());

LookAtCars(listOfCarObjects);
```

---

```
public void LookAtCars(List<objects> cars)
{
   foreach(var item in cars)
   {
         List<object> innerList = item as List<object>
         foreach(innerItem in innerList)
         {
             //do something with innerItem
         }
   }
}
```

Would something like that help?